# Avoid duplicates in array in swift 3

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I am trying to get the data from the selected rows in my tableView inside an array. I will append the selected row to the array and this does work great. Unfortunately when I deselect the row and select it again it will append it again. I need to write some logic to delete the deselected row from the array.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Here is the code when I select a row:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? exerciseCell
        selectedCell?.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 84.0 / 255, green: 199.0 / 255, blue: 252.0 / 255, alpha: 1)

        rowSelected+=1

        if rowSelected >= 1 {
            nextBtn.isEnabled = true
            nextBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 84.0 / 255, green: 199.0 / 255, blue: 252.0 / 255, alpha: 1)
        }

        let exercisesSelected = selectedCell?.exerciseNameLbl.text

        exerisenames.append(exercisesSelected!)

        print(exerisenames)

    }
```

Here is the code for deselecting a row:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? exerciseCell
        selectedCell?.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.darkGray

        rowSelected-=1

        if rowSelected == 0 {
            nextBtn.isEnabled = false
            nextBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
            nextBtn.setTitle("Choose an exercise", for: UIControlState.disabled)
        }

        let exercisesDeselected = selectedCell?.exerciseNameLbl.text


        if exerisenames.contains(exercisesDeselected!) {
            print("exercise already in the row and has to be deleted before going further")
        }

        print(exerisenames)

    }
```

Both will refer to an array that I created in the top called: exercisenames

Comment: `exerisenames.removeObject(exercisesDeselected)`

Comment: it gives me the error that [String] has no member removeObject

Comment: Why not use the set instead of array?

Comment: @almas because OP might want to persist the order.

Comment: Why not use ordered set?

Comment: It might help if you said what version of Swift you're using.

Comment: @TomHarrington I am using swift 3 and xcode 8.0

Answer (score 0):

From a quick look at the docs, you probably want something like

```
if let index = exercisenames.index(of: exercisesDeselected) {
    exercisenames.remove(at: index)
}
```

But I also think that @almas's suggestion of an ordered set might be good.

Comment: But what is index in this case? I have multiple rows in my tableView. And what if I select row 3 first and delete row 2. and vice versa?

Comment: @KevinVugts index is the location of the element i.e. exercisesDeselected for this case. If it does exist, you delete it. But after doing this, the array contents are shifted so another element will be stored in that location

Comment: It's exactly what the code says-- the result of calling `index(of:)` on your array. That returns the index in the array. You might want to take a look at the Swift docs, this is all in there.

Comment: its gives me the error: Cannot invoke index with an argument list of type of:string

Comment: Check your code, because it can remove strings. Did you include the `of:`?